# TableView with Array (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview

I have a Problem with the Arrays, I have tried to load my
TableView data from a MutableArray. But I failed when trying...
I get no mistakes, but if I open the TableView, the View is empty.
Here is my Code, maybe you have any ideas.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"Wert von tE nachdem die Seite geladen hat, ist wie folgt: %d", trickEins);

}

-(NSMutableArray *)mutableArrayAusTricksArray:(NSArray *)array {

    NSLog(@"Wert: %d", trickEins);

    self.tricksFavoriten = [NSMutableArray new];

    if (trickEins  == 2)  {[self.tricksFavoriten addObject:@"Body Feint"];};
    if (trickZwei  == 2)  {[self.tricksFavoriten addObject:@"Stepover"];};
    if (trickDrei  == 2)  {[self.tricksFavoriten addObject:@"Reverse Stepover"];};
    if (trickVier  == 2)  {[self.tricksFavoriten addObject:@"Ball Roll"];};
    if (trickFuenf == 2)  {[self.tricksFavoriten addObject:@"Drag Back"];};
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    return self.tricksFavoriten;

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    return [self.tricksFavoriten count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = self.tricksFavoriten[indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}



@end
```

Comment: Please note that this question is not related to Xcode.

Comment: Excuse me, is my first Question here.

Comment: @user2597038 H2CO3 can be a douche sometimes. Ignore it. He's just let ting you know. He is nice though.

Comment: @Henry Harris Hahaha ok I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of sections should be 1.

**Edit:** In viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   [self.tableView reloadData];
   NSLog(@"Wert von tE nachdem die Seite geladen hat, ist wie folgt: %d", trickEins);
   [self mutableArrayAusTricksArray:[[NSArray alloc]init]];

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it isn't the solution :/

Comment: Did you set your table view's dataSource and delegate?  Are any of your delegate or dataSource methods being called?

Comment: @user2597038 Did you set the cell identifier in your storyboard?

Comment: @Abdullah Shafique Yes, I have

Comment: @Nicholas Hart Yes, I think so

Comment: @user2597038 When does mutableArrayAusTricksArray: get called.

Comment: @user2597038 When does mutableArrayAusTricksArray: get called.

Comment: Put some logging in or set some breakpoints. Make sure your array isn't empty.  Make sure your table view's delegate and dataSource are not nil.  Make sure your table view methods are getting called.

Comment: @Abdullah Shafique ohh how can I do this?